# Vue: How to use Directives from Libraries

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Im trying to use this library: https://github.com/rigor789/vue-scrollto

But Im having trouble using it and the instructions are not very helpful to me. it says I should do this:

```
var Vue = require('vue');
var VueScrollTo = require('vue-scrollto');

Vue.use(VueScrollTo)
```

But I have no idea where to do this. So I have tried just using it like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Navbar/>
    <Cover/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" v-scroll-to="'#about'">Hallo</button>
    <Offers/>
    <AboutUs id="about"/>
    <Info/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar'
import Cover from '@/components/main/Cover'
import Offers from '@/components/main/Offer/Offers'
import AboutUs from '@/components/main/AboutUs'
import Info from '@/components/main/Info'
import Menu from '@/components/main/menu/Menu'

var Vue = require('vue');
var VueScrollTo = require('vue-scrollto');

Vue.use(VueScrollTo)

export default {
  components: {
    Navbar,
    Cover,
    Offers,
    AboutUs,
    Info,
    Menu
  }
}
</script>
```

But that doesn't work. So how do I import libraries properly so I can use the directives?

Comment: wherever you import Vue and start your app. `app.js` or `index.js` normally. It will be usable in any component.

Comment: any error in the console? if failed to add directive=`scroll-to`, Vue will throw out one warning like `v-scroll-to doesn't exists`. if no, it should be something else caused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `import` instead of using `require`.

The `es6` script will be transpiled to old js versions when you build the app.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Navbar/>
    <Cover/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" v-scroll-to="'#about'">Hallo</button>
    <Offers/>
    <AboutUs id="about"/>
    <Info/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar'
import Cover from '@/components/main/Cover'
import Offers from '@/components/main/Offer/Offers'
import AboutUs from '@/components/main/AboutUs'
import Info from '@/components/main/Info'
import Menu from '@/components/main/menu/Menu'

import Vue from 'vue';
import VueScrollTo from 'vue-scrollto';

Vue.use(VueScrollTo)

export default {
  components: {
    Navbar,
    Cover,
    Offers,
    AboutUs,
    Info,
    Menu
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I replaced the require and because I use nuxt.js I did it a little different.

Answer (score 1):

So bacause I use Vue it did the following:

create a new file called nuxt-scroll-to.js in the plugins folder with this code:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueScrollTo from 'vue-scrollto/vue-scrollto.js';

Vue.use(VueScrollTo)
```

and the in the nuxt.config.js array add this code: `{ src: '~/plugins/nuxt-scroll-to.js', ssr: false },`